# Regex to Filter string with unicode characters and emojis for java

Tags: java, regex, spring-boot, unicode, emoji

I'm developing a Spring boot chat application. How can I create a regex to achieve followings,

- Remove special characters
- remove newlines tabs etc..
- Accept Unicode characters
- Accept for emojis

further,
DB tables `CHARACTER SET` `utf8mb4` and `COLLATE` `utf8mb4_bin`.

Comment: _All_ characters that you can process with Java are Unicode characters.

Comment: Some evidence of effort on your part is expected. Show your regex.

Answer (score 1):

- Remove special characters

  ```
  s = s.replaceAll("[\\p{P}\\p{S}]", "")
  ```
- remove newlines tabs etc..

  ```
  s = s.replaceAll("[\\p{C}\\p{Zl}\\p{Zp}]", "")
  ```
- Accept Unicode characters
  *Java already does this.*
- Accept for emojis
  *Emojis are Unicode characters, so Java already does this.*

All-in-all:

```
s = s.replaceAll("[\\p{P}\\p{S}\\p{C}\\p{Zl}\\p{Zp}]", "")
```

For list of Unicode Categories and the Characters in each Category, see [Unicode Character Categories](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm).

With the above regex, the following categories are retained: `L` (Letter), `M` (Mark), `N` (Number), `Zs` (Separator, Space).